# Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface

Tags: weblogic12c, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have tried to generate the java code from wsdl2java by using cxf-codegen-plugin .
Code was generated and can see the response in my eclipse test class(tried to call few methods and getting result properly).
But when I created jar of this code and moved to Weblogic server classpath (I have few jsp pages calling this wsdl2java generated code), It calling my methods properly but every time getting Runtime exception.

Note: I have moved all the dependent jars too inside weblogic classpath.

Below is the Exception snapshot:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: MASM0015: Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.<init>(TubeCreator.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.initializeTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
    at customeruserextv2.loginservice.LoginService.getLoginServiceSoap(LoginService.java:93)
    at com.ncs.wcm.LoginHelper.login(LoginHelper.java:50)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._cs_deployed._testportal.__userlogin._jspService(__userlogin.java:322)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:492)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:379)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:637)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:508)
```

Below is the method which I am calling and getting error:

```
public static boolean login(String userName, String password) {
          URL wsdlURL = LoginService.WSDL_LOCATION;
            LoginService ss = new LoginService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
            LoginServiceSoap port = ss.getLoginServiceSoap(); // This is the line where throwing error
        return port.login(userName, password);
}
```

Below my POM.xml

```
<description>LoginServiceWcm</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  
  <build>
        <finalName>LoginService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/login.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/login.wsdl</wsdlLocation>

                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```